# Finding values of $n$ where $\frac{xn}{x-n}$ is an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to figure values of $n$ that make the quation $\frac{xn}{x-n}$ an integer where $x$ is a known positive integers. I was trying to rewrite this as as $xn = \lambda (x-n)$ where $\lambda$ is another unknown integer, but I feel this makes it more complicated. For $x=4$, the values $n=5,6,8,12,20$ all work. Is there any way that I can find all the values of $n$ that fulfill this for a certain $x$? Or at least finding an upper limit on $n$ that would allow me to write a program to find all the values of $n$ that could work and checking each one?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{xn}{x-n} = -x + \frac{x^2}{x-n}$.

Comment: Ahhh, that helped a lot. I just have to find all the factors of $x^2$ then all the values of $n$ are those factors $+x$. Thank you.

Comment: Well if $k = \gcd(x,n)$ and $x = x'k; n =n'k$ we have $\frac {kx'n'}{x'-n'}$ is an integer.  And $\gcd(x',n') = 1$ and $\gcd(x',x-n') = \gcd(n',x-n')=1$ so $x'-n'|k$.

Comment: Right, just be careful that you need to consider the negative factors of $x^2$ as well, even if you want to restrict $n$ to be a positive (or nonnegative) integer.  So for example, for $x=4$, the values $n=3, 2, 0$ also work.